# Tengo un inconveniente al instalar pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

me sale el siguiente mensaje luego de poner la forma de instalación según e encontrado en diferentes paginas, también intente buscar el error pero al parecer no es muy comun

```
C:\Users\leandro\Documents\Python\practica>pip install pymongo
Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in 
c:\users\leandro\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages 
(3.9.0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la pregunta sólo se observa que pymongo ya está instalado, no es un error.

De todas formas, si no te funciona puede deberse a que tienes instalada alguna versión incompatible de algún módulo o paquete del que depende pymongo. Si este es el caso:

Prueba a crear un entorno virtual. Para ello instala **virtualenv**:

```
python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Crea un directorio y en este ejecuta:

```
python -m virtualenv myvenv
```

Entra en el directorio *myvenv* que se ha creado. Si estás en *Windows* debes ejecutar el archivo **activate.bat** (dentro de la carpeta *Scripts*) desde *cmd* para iniciar el entorno virtual (en *Linux* creo que *activate* se encuentra en el directorio *bin*).

Una vez inicializado el *virtualenv* ejecuta:

```
pip install pymongo
```

Si se instala correctamente puedes utilizar *pymongo* desde este entorno virtual, y significa que efectivamente existe algún conflicto con los paquetes de los que depende pymongo en tu instalación de *Python*.